# Including a step STM in textrecipes

Tags: tidymodels, r-recipes

How can I use STM in textrecipes? (tidymodels workflow)

I need this for my master's degree where I use textrecipes as the main package.
The link https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/recipes/ shows how to create a new step in my recipe, but I can't get out of zero with that.

Comment: Can you share a little more detail about what you are trying to do? The stm ([structural topic model](https://www.structuraltopicmodel.com/)) is an unsupervised ML algorithm, while textrecipes focuses on feature engineering for supervised (predictive) ML algorithms.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, it might be work taking it over on https://github.com/tidymodels/textrecipes/issues as a feature request.

Comment: Hi Mrs. @JuliaSilge and Mr. EmilHvitfeldt, how nice to talk to you (you're my main references in text analysis).
Sorry for my shallow English; by the way, I work with texts in Brazilian Portuguese.
The problem consists of examining whether the STM output can be used in a supervised classification problem to predict "conviction", or not, in antitrust conduct judgments in Brazil. Ultimately, the impact of a topic to a judgment.
I read https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/recipes/ but I couldn't program a step_STM.